# ASP.Net Entity Framework Project Main Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I created an ASP.Net Entity Framework project by using an empty template and then I created two web forms: webform1 and webform2. How do I get webform1 to be the first page displayed every time I start the program?

I went through every file but couldn't find a place to set the route

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

you have to right-click on the page and select Set As Start Page and then run the application.

[image]

you can also select like this.

Go to

[image]

And then Select your startup page.

[image]

But I would say that the world is evolving now, Web forms are pretty old, if it's a new project then consider Asp.Net Core.